# How to understand the geometry of the non-zero rows in RREF form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Below, we see Gaussian elimination to go from [A b] -> [U d].
[image]

Strang says, the column space of A can be completely characterized by the equation:

$b_3 + b_2 - 5b_1 = 0 \tag{1}$

My question is, what about the equations in row 1 and 2? Don't these impose some constraints that have some geometric meaning? Why can the entire column space be summarized by the single plane equation in (1)?

If instead, we have as the final [U d]:

$
 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & | &b_1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & | & b_2 - 2b_1 
\end{bmatrix}
$

In other words, removing the final row. What can we say bout the geometry of this new [U d] and how is it different from before?

Comment: @DonAntonio Why is it $\iff$? Don't the other two rows above row 3 have an effect? Also see my update where I propose removing the last row.

Comment: No, they don't, because once $\;b_3+b_2-5b_1=0\;$ then you're left with an equivalent system with two rows and three variables and thus it has infinite solutions

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "geometric" meaning you mean, but what Strang means is that the system is solvable iff $\;b_3+b_2-5b_1=0\;$. and once this happens then you can try to find the solutions.

Once the above is fulfilled, you look at

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & | &b_1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & | & b_2 - 2b_1 
\end{pmatrix}\;\;\implies \begin{cases}R_2:\;\; 2z=2\implies  z=1\\{}\\R_1:\;\;x+2y+3=5\implies x=2-2y\end{cases}\;\;\implies$$

$$\text{The solution is}\;\;\left\{(2-2y,\,y,\,1)\;|;y\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

or $\;y\;$ in any field over which you're working.